# BibTex reference not showing up correctly

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

I've been trying to cite this article

```
@article{office2012national,
  title={National Strategy for Suicide Prevention Goals and Objectives for Action Summary List},
  author={Office of the Surgeon General (US and National Action Alliance for Suicide Prevention (US and others))},
  year={2012},
  publisher={US Department of Health \& Human Services (US)}
```

}

using

```
\bibliographystyle{acm-sigchi}
```

but regardless of how much I try, it always shows up like this

[image]

I tried removing some extra brackets from above (copied directly from Google Scholar search) and replacing the ampersand character, but that does little to change the output. Thank you for the help!